# Problem while capturing ALT key event in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, keyboard

I need to enable `alt-<key>` selection semantics for some Buttons in my application. If I write KeyDownEventListener for the Button, its not getting triggered when I press ALT key in the keyboard. Is there any way to enable alt key semantics for the buttons?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`KeyboadEvent` class has an [altKey](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#altKey) property that you can use to check if Alt key was held-down while the current key was pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. but when i press some key along with altkey, the event is not getting fired. so iam unable to read that property

Comment: I just read the docs and found that it is supported only in windows - went on and tested in windows to find that it is fired only when you press alt + ctrl. It seems you are gonna have to resort to some other key like ctrl key