# ALT capturing in Flex apps (yet again)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I know there have been similar threads in the past but I can't seem to find a decent definitive answer / workaround for the problem I'm facing.

What I'm trying to do:
capture ALT+SHIFT+something keyboard events. Pretty straightforward, right?

Issue:
When pressing ALT+SHIFT doesn't seem to ever shoot an event. The only combination that seems to work with ALT is CTRL+ALT+something, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789609/problem-while-capturing-alt-key-event-in-flex).

Question:
really? I've read that the browser catches some of the keyboard events, but this happens with the basic flash player too - maybe that catches events too? Would love to know if there is a solution that doesn't involve messing with JS.

thank you!

Comment: Your research is correct. You aren't going to get access to that key combination. Why is a completely different matter (You'd have to find an adobe engineer for that one!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as you've said is that the browser captures some of the key combinations, and the underlying OS may catch others. From the research I've done, and read about on the bug on Adobe's bug base I filed on this, it can be made better if you do an Air app, but even then there are some of these combinations that are just eaten by the OS, so it never even comes NEAR your application.